# I would leave vs I will leave

Tags: word-usage

You're getting bored in a party, and you want to leave right now. Which of the following sentence is correct?

> I would leave now.
>
> I will leave now.

What I am asking is which of the two sentence is better to use in that situation when you want to leave right now, as I am learning that "Would" is used in present tense and "Will" in future. But I think I have heard *will* in these types of sentences when *would* is grammatically more correct.

Comment: Remember you can edit your question to add details. You don't need to add a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I will leave" is correct. This is the simple future. As you are speaking you are still present so when you leave is in the future.

"I would leave" has a number of possible interpretations. The most likely is the condtional "I would leave (if something)"  This implies that you are *not* leaving, because the condition hasn't been met.

> Are you still at the party? I thought you were bored.
>
> I would leave, but I don't have any money for a taxi. So I have to stay here until my dad picks me up.

("Would" has several other meanings, such as the past tense of "will" in reported speech, and for indicating past habit, but these don't apply to this context.)

I wouldn't use "will" or "would".  You are speaking about "right now" so you should use a present tense.

> I'm leaving. Goodbye!

The present continuous can be used to describe events that are happening while the speaker is speaking and will continue into the future. The present continuous is the right choice of tense in this context.